# ConverseJS: how to enable sound notifications for all messages in a muc chat room?

Tags: javascript, converse.js

The `play_sounds` option in [ConverseJS](https://conversejs.org/) (version 3.2) allows "playing a notification sound when you receive a personal message or when your nickname is mentioned in a chat room" ([see here](https://m.conversejs.org/docs/html/configuration.html#play-sounds)). Is there a way to play sound for every new message in the muc chat room, not just the ones that mention a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do this.

Use the [notify_all_room_messages](https://conversejs.org/docs/html/configuration.html#notify-all-room-messages) setting.

From the above link:

*If you set this setting to true, then you will be notified of all messages received in a room.*

This refers to both sound notifications and HTML5 desktop notifications.

To have notifications for only some rooms:

```
converse.initialize({
        // Other config settings omitted for brevity
        // ...

        notify_all_room_messages: [                                                  
            'foo@conference.exampl.org',
            'bar@conference.example.org',                            
                   │
        ]
});
```

Or to enable notifications for all rooms:

```
converse.initialize({
        // Other config settings omitted for brevity
        // ...

        notify_all_room_messages: true                                               
});
```